# redis bind address localhost with (double colon) ::1

Tags: configuration, bind, redis

This may be the noobiest question ever, but can someone tell me what the `::1` means in redis configuration for `bind`? E.g.:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

In a docker image made my colleagues, this was the set value, and redis would not start because it could not bind to the address, but when I removed the `::1`, it worked.

Comment: IPv6 address for localhost?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli wow i did not know that, thanks